# Ansible pyenv virtualenv gives error for pip?

Tags: python, pip, ansible, pyenv

I have ansible task

```
- name: Install setuptools in virtual environment
  pip:
      name: setuptools-git
      virtualenv: "myenv"
      virtualenv_command: "/root/.pyenv/bin/pyenv virtualenv 2.7.13"
```

But it gives error

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "chdir": null,
            "editable": false,
            "executable": null,
            "extra_args": "",
            "name": [
                "setuptools-git"
            ],
            "requirements": null,
            "state": "present",
            "umask": null,
            "use_mirrors": true,
            "version": null,
            "virtualenv": "myenv",
            "virtualenv_command": "/root/.pyenv/bin/pyenv virtualenv 2.7.13",
            "virtualenv_python": null,
            "virtualenv_site_packages": false
        }
    },
    "msg": "Unable to find pip in the virtualenv, myenv, under any of these names: pip2, pip. Make sure pip is present in the virtualenv."
}
```

When I check the pip file in virtualenv, its already there

```
# ls -alh /root/.pyenv/versions/myenv/bin/pip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 243 Jan 16 17:40 /root/.pyenv/versions/myenv/bin/pip
```

There are 2 virtualenvs for same name

```
# /root/.pyenv/bin/pyenv virtualenvs
2.7.13/envs/myenv (created from /root/.pyenv/versions/2.7.13)
myenv (created from /root/.pyenv/versions/2.7.13)
```

I cant use `executable` with `virtualenv` variable.

Comment: Shall we assume `/root/.pyenv/versions/myenv/bin/pip` is symlinked to `2.7.13`?

Comment: @techraf I updated my question, hope you get your answer in that

Answer (score 2):

I found a **workaround** to install packages with pip into a virtualenv managed by pyenv. It does avoid using the pip module and instead just executes some shell commands. I am providing some variables I used, a *.pyenvrc* file I created, and the ansible task that does the shell magic.

**Variables**:

```
# Installation paths
pyenv_root: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/.pyenv"
pyenv_rc: "{{ pyenv_root }}/.pyenvrc"
# Whatever your virtualenv is named
pyenv_venv_name: "foo_virtualenv"
project_dir: /path/to/your/project
```

**Tasks**:

```
- name: Pip - install requirements using shell
  shell: |
    # cd to project directory
    cd {{ project_dir }}
    # Check to see if we are already inside a virtualenv
    if ! [[ ${VIRTUAL_ENV} ]]; then
        # Load pyenv into the shell
        source {{ pyenv_rc }}
        # Activate the virtualenv
        pyenv activate {{ pyenv_venv_name }}
    fi
    # Install python requirements 
    pip install -r requirements.txt
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  register: pip_script_result
```

Contents of *.pyenvrc*:

```sh
# Add pyenv into path if installed into default location
export PYENV_ROOT="{{ pyenv_root }}"
export PATH="${PYENV_ROOT}/bin:${PATH}"

# Initialise pyenv and pyenv-virtualenv if installed
if [[ -d $HOME/.pyenv ]];then
    eval "$(pyenv init -)"
    if [ -d "${PYENV_ROOT}/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv" ]; then
        eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
    fi
fi

# Disable prompt changing
export PYENV_VIRTUALENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1
```

In the above example, I installed the contents of *requirements.txt* using `pip` into my pyenv managed virtualenv. You should be able to adapt the `pip install` line to do whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

Basically for `virtualenv` attribute, you have to pass virtual env path. See the below example.

```
- hosts: 1.2.3.4
  user: remoteuser
  environment:
    PYENV_ROOT: /home/<user home dir>/.pyenv
    PYENV_VERSION: myenv
    PYENV_SHELL: bash
    PYENV_ACTIVATE_SHELL: 1
  tasks:
  - pip:
      name: setuptools-git
      virtualenv: "/home/<user home dir>/.pyenv/versions/myenv"
      virtualenv_command: /home/<user home dir>/.pyenv/bin/pyenv virtualenv 3.4.0 myenv
```

I Hope, this will solve your issue.